# Adding Numbers after extracting with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am just trying to add sizes of my files with a bash script.

```
# ls -lh | awk '{print $5}' | tr "M" " "

59 
292 
34 
55 
90 
78 
78 
53 
57 
105 
26 
8.6 
8.3 
38 
74 
937 
48
```

Up to this i made it fine but when I am trying to add all this numbers

```
# for i in [`ls -lh | awk '{print $5}' | tr "M" " " `]; do sum=$(($sum+$i)); done
```

I am getting below error.

```
  -bash: +[: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[")
```

Somebody help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: You could just do the sum in awk. And if you use `ls -lk` all the sizes will be in the same units. At the moment you are adding sizes in K and M together as if they were the same. `ls -lk | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -l | awk '{print $5}' | tr "M" " "| awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'`

Comment: Its working.Thank you.Wait for 8 Min. So I can accept.

Comment: As @patthoyts points out this will not take into account different units (K, M, G...) conveniently given by the `-h` flag passed to `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

- First rule: [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It's meant for humans, not scripts. Use `find` of file globbing instead.
- You're trying to use `[]` to delimit a list - that's neither allowed nor necessary.
- Avoid backticks, prefer `$( )` - less hassle with quoting.

Here's how you could do this with `bash` and `stat`:

```
sum=0
for file in * ; do
  sum=$(( sum + $(stat -c%s "$file") ))
done
echo $sum
```

Or with `find` and `awk`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This one's a bit convoluted:

```
total=$( { stat -c '%s' * | tr '\n' '+'; echo 0; } | bc )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please dont mind , actually `ls -lh` it self calculates the size of total files.Just now I figure it out.

```
# ls -lh
total 2.0G
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too - `du` will skip subdirectories with `-S`, summarize with `-s` and print in human readable with `-h`:

```
du -Ssh
```